# sqlsrv_query() for a linux system?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, linux

This question is related to a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609043/is-this-sufficient-to-prevent-query-injection-while-using-sql-server).

Is there something comparable to sqlsrv_query() on a linux server?

Or something extremely simple to parameterize queries for a LAMP(php)/SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and the [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) class.  It will work with all the [major databases](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php), including MySQL and SQL Server.