# In MySQL, should I quote numbers or not?

Tags: mysql, sql, ansi-sql

For example - I create database  and a table from cli and insert some data:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
USE testdb;
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, str VARCHAR(100)) TYPE=innodb CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
INSERT INTO test VALUES (9, 'some string');
```

Now I can do this and these examples do work (so - quotes don't affect anything it seems):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = '9';
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('11', 'some string');
```

So - in these examples I've selected a row by a **string** that actually stored as INT in mysql and then I inserted a **string** in a column that is INT.

I don't quite get why this works the way it works here. Why is string allowed to be inserted in an INT column?

Can I insert all MySQL data types as strings?

Is this behavior standard across different RDBMS?

Answer (score 71):

MySQL is a lot like PHP, and will auto-convert data types as best it can. Since you're working with an int field (left-hand side), it'll try to transparently convert the right-hand-side of the argument into an int as well, so `'9'` just becomes `9`.

Strictly speaking, the quotes are unnecessary, and force MySQL to do a typecasting/conversion, so it wastes a bit of CPU time. In practice, unless you're running a Google-sized operation, such conversion overhead is going to be microscopically small.

Comment: I think the quotes can also lead to a situation where an index is not used because of the casting. So I too recommend to do it properly and never use quotes on numbers. That will also make a possible transition to a more standard compliant DBMS easier.

Comment: I guess my primary beef was: when I do inserts from PHP - all numbers are quoted by default. It looks like I MUST use PDO::PARAM_INT for number to be unquoted. I simply don't get why so many examples online omit these really required PDO::PARAM_ constants.

Comment: PDO, for all that it's the generally recommended solution, is a total pile of crap when it comes to bound parameters and type-conversion.

Comment: @marc B: what do u recommend? mysqli? mmm. I don't recall any other alternative. Mysql C api defines code for each mysql type: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-prepared-statement-type-codes.html, but either mysqli or PDO only give you 4-5 type bindings. mysqli: (i,f,s,d) and PDO: (PDO::PARAM_INT, PDO::PARAM_STR etc.)

Comment: Any of the mysql libraries work fine, it's just that PDO lets people be lazy and not have to deal with escaping things themselves. On the other hand, there's a fair number of query-types that CAN'T be done with prepared statements and you'll have to go "bare metal" instead./

Comment: So I suppose without quotes would be faster?

Comment: What if I have a varchar column with only numbers as registries. Maybe you ask why and the answer is because i have some registries beginning with a zero as '0203'. So, what is better for me? A simple query like SELECT * FROM my_col WHERE my_registry = 203, or SELECT * FROM my_col WHERE my_registry = '0203'?

Answer (score 14):

You should never put quotes around numbers.  There is a valid reason for this.

The real issue comes down to type casting.  When you put numbers inside quotes, it is treated as a string and MySQL must convert it to a number before it can execute the query.  While this may take a small amount of time, the real problems start to occur when MySQL doesn't do a good job of converting your string.  For example, MySQL will convert basic strings like '123' to the integer 123, but will convert some larger numbers, like '18015376320243459', to floating point.  Since floating point can be rounded, your queries may return inconsistent results. [Learn more about type casting here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html). Depending on your server hardware and software, these results will vary. MySQL explains this.

If you are worried about SQL injections, always check the value first and use PHP to strip out any non numbers.  You can use preg_replace for this: `preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string)`

In addition, if you write your SQL queries with quotes they will not work on databases like PostgreSQL or Oracle.

Comment: Then why does mysql put quotes around numbers we right click -> Copy row in Workbench?? There's like 5 different copy row options, but not one of them can tell if a column is a number or not.

Answer (score 4):

Check this, you can understand better ...

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1) FROM test_no WHERE varchar_num=0000194701461220130201115347;
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                  | type  | possible_keys     | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_no | index | Uniq_idx_varchar_num | Uniq_idx_varchar_num | 63      | NULL | 3126240 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1) FROM test_no WHERE varchar_num='0000194701461220130201115347';
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                  | type  | possible_keys     | key               | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_no | const | Uniq_idx_varchar_num | Uniq_idx_varchar_num | 63      | const |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
mysql> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM test_no WHERE varchar_num=0000194701461220130201115347;
+----------+
| COUNT(1) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (7.94 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM test_no WHERE varchar_num='0000194701461220130201115347';
+----------+
| COUNT(1) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: With some more explanation this could be a very instructive answer.

Comment: It looks ilke it's just wayyy slower if you don't provide quotes

Comment: @ahnbizcad my guess is because the quoted query was ran second and could take advantage of the first query being cached

Comment: @apricity, No, that's not it. For one thing, the second query would result in a separate cache entry. But even if you disable the query cache, it will be much faster, because it will do an efficient index lookup instead of an index scan. Look at the `rows` field reported by the EXPLAINs.

Answer (score 3):

This is not standard behavior.

For MySQL 5.5. this is the default SQL Mode

```
mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+------------+
| @@sql_mode |
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

ANSI and TRADITIONAL are used more rigorously by Oracle and PostgreSQL. [The SQL Modes MySQL permits must be set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html) **IF AND ONLY IF** you want to make the SQL more ANSI-compliant. Otherwise, you don't have to touch a thing. I've never done so.

Comment: I'm curious - how does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: umm. yeah. i'm not changing mode to ansi or traditional. I have default mysql setup.

Comment: The last part says : Is this behavior standard across different RDBMS? Let me clarify: It is not standard behavior for different RDBMS's.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK it is standard, but it is considered bad practice because
- using it in a WHERE clause will prevent the optimizer from using indices (explain plan should show that)
- the database has to do additional work to convert the string to a number
- if you're using this for floating-point numbers ('9.4'), you'll run into trouble if client and server use different language settings (9.4 vs 9,4)

In short: don't do it (but YMMV)

Comment: Where did you get the information that indices are not used? My EXPLAIN result looks exactly the same with or without quotes

Comment: According to the MySQL 5.6 documentation, indices are not used when comparing *string columns* to *integer values*: "For comparisons of a string column with a number, MySQL cannot use an index on the column to look up the value quickly. If str_col is an indexed string column, the index cannot be used when performing the lookup in the following statement:" - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html . Although the OP's scenario is the other way around, I'd still not rely on the RDBMS to use indices in that case (AFAIK, at least one other major RDBMS (Oracle) doesn't).

Comment: It works fine with MySQL, and properly uses the index. Personally, I wrap *everything* in single quotes when working with MySQL to standardize things, and it just means I don't use BOOL values in MySQL. I guess when I first did it I was nervous someone could more easily escape out of a value if it wasn't wrapped with single-quotes, but that's poppy-cock.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the column type!
if you run

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 0;
```

in mysql/maria-db you will get all the records where `username` IS NOT NULL.

Always quote values if the column is of type string (char, varchar,...) otherwise you'll get unexpected results!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to quote the numbers but it is always a good habit if you do as it is consistent.

Comment: why is this consistent? could you please explain that?

Comment: 1 OR 1=1 or something similar that can cause unnecessary load on the server or sql injection if unquoted. It becomes a second nature to quote everything in a sql query however if you are picky and then a sql query that should have been quoted as number is not, then sql injection may occur (check online for this and how many victims there are to it). Although quoting numbers does cause a little load on the server but even if you performing around 100K queries every second still you would only save a total of 11 seconds for 100K queries which comes down to less that a millisecond for each query.

Comment: It converts the datatype itself.

Comment: quoting does **not** help against sql injection

Comment: it does...it breaks the sql query. We are still assuming that you are going to escape the data for the numbers aswell.

Comment: well, escaping (or casting) data helps. quoting does not.

Comment: @wonk0 Anush's argument regarding **security** would seem to be perfectly valid. From the [MySQL manual page on Security Guidelines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/security-guidelines.html) - "A common mistake is to protect only string data values. Remember to check numeric data as well. If an application generates a query such as SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=234 when a user enters the value 234, the user can enter the value 234 OR 1=1 to cause the application to generate the query SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=234 OR 1=1. As a result, the server retrieves every row in the table. ...

Comment: ...cont... This exposes every row and causes excessive server load. The simplest way to protect from this type of attack is to use single quotation marks around the numeric constants: SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID='234'. If the user enters extra information, it all becomes part of the string. In a numeric context, MySQL automatically converts this string to a number and strips any trailing nonnumeric characters from it."

Comment: @w3d that is exactly what wonk0 said. If you don't escape it, you can always inject. But making a string out of it doesn't help a bit.
To take your example: If the user enters 234' OR 1=1 -- , you still have an injection. 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID='234' OR 1=1 -- '
TL;DR: Just sanitize your input. (And use prepared statements where avaliable)

Comment: @domenukk: Well, the quoting primarily helps in the first example. If the data is only escaped (which Anush had assumed but only states in his last comment) then the attack is still present and quoting the value makes this harmless: `'234 OR 1=1'`. Your example would become `'234\' OR 1=1'` (which is still valid), but without the quotes it would break. But I agree, this is a poor mans protection. Like you say, sanitizing/parameterized queries are preferred.

Comment: @w3d http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139199/can-i-protect-against-sql-injection-by-escaping-single-quote-and-surrounding-use

Comment: @w3d how about this input: 234\' OR 1=1 -- ? 
It becomes '234 \\' OR 1=1 -- => INJECTION.
As you said, poor mans protection. Do it proper. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, let's say that we have a table called users, which has a column called current_balance of type FLOAT, if you run this query:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `current_balance`='231608.09' WHERE `user_id`=9;
```

The current_balance field will be updated to 231608, because MySQL made a rounding, similarly if you try this query:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `current_balance`='231608.55' WHERE `user_id`=9;
```

The current_balance field will be updated to 231609

Comment: No, the current_balance field will NOT be updated to 231608 nor 231609, it will be updated to 231608.09375 and 231608.546875 respectively regardless of whether you use quotes or not. Find out yourself by SELECT `user_id`, FORMAT(`current_balance`,24) FROM `users`

Comment: Don't ever use float for absolute precision such as account balances. Use the decimal column type.