# What effect do quotes have when placed around numbers in SELECT statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was under the impression it didn't matter whether numbers were quoted or not, but when I noticed that this simple query:

```
SELECT id FROM table t WHERE t.col = 1234
```

Took `0.21s` to execute (where `id` is a `BIGINT` primary key and col is a `varchar` with an index), I knew something wasn't right.

After fiddling around a while, I tried putting quotes around the number:

```
SELECT id FROM table t WHERE t.col = "1234"
```

The execution time dropped to `0.046s`.

Is this a fluke, or *does* it matter if numbers are quoted?

EDIT: Also, how does this affect PDO queries where parameters are bound?

EDIT 2: Apparently the query plans are different:

Without quotes:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys    | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ALL  | ind_col          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 99431 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

With quotes:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ref  | ind_col          | ind_col          | 767     | const |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: When you give the query a number, it takes time to convert it to a string before doing the comparison.

Comment: Looks like it has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781976/mysql-quote-numbers-or-not

Comment: is it a non numeric column?

Comment: @DanielWilliams `t.col` is a varchar(255) with an index.

Comment: this is the expected behavior then. you cannot use a string type index to help search for a numeric type. mysql will have to do a full table scan. it will however work in the reverse case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of performance they do not matter for mysql. For when to use them you can see this question [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

You are most likely experiencing a warmed up buffer pool or query caching. Also, when I locally query a remote a sql machine in amazon I can have variability in response time just from my own network performance and remote machine load. If you want to really test it out try profiling the query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html

For this specific case it is an eccentricity of mysql that you cannot use a string type index when querying for a numeric value. The reverse however works.