# Why does enclosing a field in quotes take longer than without it?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, key

For example, I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE field IN (-1, "1")
```

The above query takes 20 times longer than this one to execute. Why?

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE field IN (-1, 1)
```

Also, in the first case the **index** is not used, even with `USE INDEX`.

Comment: Have you tried running `EXPLAIN` to see if the execution is different?

Comment: Also, see the link on Mike's answer, as it explains both how the conversion can take up CPU time, as well as how the quotes may lead to scenarios where an index is not being used as a result.

Comment: What is the datatype of `a`?

Comment: Did you run the query twice?  Caching may be involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely because MySQL is converting `field` to CHAR, and not `"1"` to INT.

See how long this runs:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE field IN (-1, CAST("1" AS INT));
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6782019/3131147) answer for more info. It sounds like MySQL is actually converting "1" (a char) to an int(because that matches the type of field), but still, this conversion process takes time, and that's why it runs longer.