# I cant make my PHP code change values on a database

Tags: php, database

I'm new at coding and I'm trying to learn PHP and other languages all by my self. But I'm having an issue in my code, the code that I wrote to change values on a database isn't working at all. Do you guys have any idea?

```
if(spin($color)){ 
    $wonlast = true;
    $moneypot +=  $current_bet;
    $result_text .= "Winner!<br/>";
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE store_players SET `credits` = $moneypot WHERE `id` = 1");
  }else{
    $result_text.= "Loser<br/>";
    $wonlast = false;
    $moneypot -=  $current_bet;
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE store_players SET `credits` = $moneypot WHERE `id` = 1");
  }
```

Comment: is credits and integer type column?

Comment: credits is a row, but where is integer?

Comment: `if(spin($color))` does what exactly?

Comment: after the script choose randomly the color it says if you lost or won and how many credits you lost/won and that is the point, I cant update the data on the db

Comment: and this doesn work aswel

$con = "UPDATE store_players SET `credits` = $moneypot WHERE `id` = 1";

Comment: A: total rewrite with full db creation codes. This has been going on for a tad bit long, wouldn't you agree? Besides that unknown `spin()` function that is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Update your profile's first video link to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBZ4Y9LZrhY), they disabled it.

Comment: @Xorifelse thanks for letting me know, done. *Cheers* I'll get a live version later on.

Comment: @Fred-ii- A darn shame, yes. The live version sounded perfect. But heh, I'm stackoverflowing while listening to it so I'm not paying attention to it anyways.

Comment: @Xorifelse I checked some of my other vids; they've blocked those too. Now I have to go find new ones. I guess they're just too hot for some haha

Comment: @Fred-ii- Don't you worry, I only need the first link to get me started. I'm at Tightrope right now.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to learn programming on your own? Fine, I'll bite. First rule of programming, handle your output correctly. Never, ever think a query will magically always works. It returns a value for a reason.

```
if(spin($color)){ 
  $wonlast = true;
  $moneypot +=  $current_bet;
  $result_text .= "Winner!<br/>";
}else{
  $result_text.= "Loser<br/>";
  $wonlast = false;
  $moneypot -=  $current_bet;
}

if(($result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE store_players SET `credits` = $moneypot WHERE `id` = 1") !== null){
  echo 'success';
} else {
  die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

And before you blindly copy paste, you have an error in your syntax, its:

```
"UPDATE store_players SET `credits` = '$moneypot' WHERE `id` = 1"
```

Comment: Tank you for warning me of what is going on and now I'm going to search to fix the issue.

Comment: And this does not account to query's only. Any function can return a value, it does so for a reason. Always check it unless you're really, really certain.

Comment: if $moneypot is numeric then you do not need quotes. It would be better to call settype to make sure that $moneypot is an int or float if there is any chance it could not be.

Comment: mysqli_query will return false if the query fails, so you just need to check this, and you should do using === or !==

Comment: @TheoTonge You are correct, but in all fairness it should be a habit to quote values. Don't expect MySQL to quote it for you, other database drivers don't.

Comment: @Xorifelse I think its actually bad practice for numeric types, it prevents mysql from using indexes properly and when setting floats you can run into problems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781976/mysql-quote-numbers-or-not

Comment: @TheoTonge After the "double" check, `mysqli_query()` returns either false or a value, so `!==` or `===` is obsolete. While I'm not sure about floats, PDO either handles them as a string, boolean or integer. So a float is considered a string and thus a quoted value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes in proper place:

```
$myConnection= mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db($myConnection, "xxx") or die ("no database");
$sql = "UPDATE store_players SET credits = '$moneypot' WHERE id = 1";

mysqli_query($myConnection, $sql)
```

Comment: single quotes are not required if setting a numeric column

Comment: And what makes this different from my answer? If you have something to add-in, fine. But this is just a copy paste from somewhere else.

Comment: I have made a focus on the quotes.