# Laravel DB Builder uses string variable as integer ID

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

One of my controllers takes an id field as `$id` and I use it on a query. When I check the query string it passes the id as string value like this:

```
select `id`, `name` from `table` where `id` = '1'
```

If I pass the `intval($id)` to the query it still works as expected.

```
select `id`, `name` from `table` where `id` = 1
```

My question: Which one is the optimized query and best practice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all**: `(int)` is faster than `intval()`.
Link: [wiki.phpbb.com/Best_Practices:PHP](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Best_Practices:PHP).
**About quote numbers or not**: In practice, unless you're running a Google-sized operation, such conversion overhead is going to be microscopically small.
Link: [stackoverflow.com/questions/6781976](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781976/mysql-quote-numbers-or-not)