# Why execute stored procedures is faster than SQL query from a script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In fact, if I call the stored procedures from my application, I need a connection to my DB.

So, why calling a "stored procedures" should be faster than "passing a SQL query" string to be executed?

Comment: There really isn't much of a speed benefit for a stored procedure anymore, these days. A properly parametrized query will be just as efficient as a stored procedure. That alone is not a good reason to use stored procedures

Answer (score 59, accepted):

SQL Server basically goes through these steps to execute **any** query (stored procedure call or ad-hoc SQL statement):

1) syntactically check the query
2) if it's okay - it checks the plan cache to see if it already has an execution plan for that query
3) if there is an execution plan - that plan is (re-)used and the query executed
4) if there is no plan yet, an execution plan is determined
5) that plan is stored into the plan cache for later reuse
6) the query is executed

The point is: ad-hoc SQL and stored procedures are treatly **no differently**.

If an ad-hoc SQL query is properly using parameters - as it should anyway, to prevent SQL injection attacks - its performance characteristics are no different and most definitely **no worse** than executing a stored procedure.

Stored procedure have other benefits (no need to grant users direct table access, for instance), but in terms of performance, using properly parametrized ad-hoc SQL queries is **just as efficient** as using stored procedures.

**Update:** using stored procedures over **non-parametrized** queries is better for two main reasons:

- since each non-parametrized query is a **new, different** query to SQL Server, it has to go through all the steps of determining the execution plan, for each query (thus wasting time - and also wasting plan cache space, since storing the execution plan into plan cache doesn't really help in the end, since that particular query will probably **not** be executed again)
- non-parametrized queries are at risk of SQL injection attack and should be avoided at all costs

Comment: P.S. SP are stored/cached...but for example if I have a "where" clauses which I pass a custom value from client, it should be compiled with that Input/condition; so for each parameter is there a dedicated SP?

Comment: @markzzz: no, in such a case, I would add a parameter to the stored procedure's definition (to be passed from the caller), and use that parameter in the "body" of the stored procedure. That way, again, you have **one** stored proc body, **one** (cached) execution plan, and you can call that with any possible value.

Comment: @marc_s: How non-parametrized queries are at a risk of sql injection as non-parametrized queries never accept any parameter.Let me know if I am wrong

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in some situations SQL Server can parameterize (AKA "auto-parameterize") non-parameterized queries, and in such cases the performance of the queries wouldn't be different, too.

Comment: What is the source for the ordering of the steps?  Are you sure a syntax check happens first?  I don't see why a simple hash and then check the plan cache for that hash wouldn't happen first before bothering parsing the statement which I would guess happens just before the compile step.

Comment: Your update should say "parameterized over non-parameterized" - there's nothing about your points that is specific to procs.  It's also worth nothing that a parameterized query calling a stored proc that uses dynamic sql is also subject to an injection attack.

Answer (score 8):

Because every time you pass a query string to SQL Server the code has to be compiled etc, stored procedures are already compiled and ready to run on the server.

Also you are sending less data over the network although this is generally a minimal impact anyway.

EDIT:
As a side note stored procedures have other benefits.

1) Security - Since the actual query is stored on the server you are not transmitting this over the network which means anyone intercepting your network traffic does not gain any insight into your table structure. Also a well designed SP will prevent injection attacks.

2) Code seperation, you keep your database code in your database and your application code in your application, there is very little crossover and I find this makes bug fixing a lot nicer.

3) Maintainability and Code Reuse, you can reuse a procedure many times without having to copy paste the query, also if you wish to update the query you just have to update it in one place.

4) Decreased network traffic. As mentioned above this may not be an issue for most people but with a large application you can significantly reduce the ammount of data being transferred via your network by switching to using stored procedures.

Comment: Any stored procedure will have to be first analyzed, execution plan determined etc. before it can be cached. Any parametrized query goes through the same process, and thus really has the same performance benefits as a stored procedure

Comment: Thats interesting thanks, I always thought that this process was actually optimised for stored procs.

Comment: But doesn't the execution plan get stored pretty much indefinitely for stored procedures and generates each time for ad hoc queries? Things might have changed, but that is how it used to be I believe.  That could mean big performance gains using stored procs.  Though if I remember correctly depending upon what you are doing in the stored proc, if it is complicated the execution plan might still be regenerated on each call.  Any comments?

Answer (score 4):

Your statement that Stored Procedures are faster than SQL Queries is only partially true. To explain: Most of these answers already explain that with stored procedures a query plan is generated and cached. So if you call the stored procedure again, the SQL engine first searches through its list of query plans and if it finds a match, it uses the optimized plan.

Passing a normal query does not allow for this advantage as the SQL engine does not know what to expect and thus it cannot find a match for your query. It creates a plan from scratch and then renders your results.

Good news: You can enable plan caching for your queries by using Parametized queries, a new feature in SQL. This enables you to generate plans for your queries and can be very effective in your situation as most of the queries you pass from code, remains the same, except for variables in the Where clause mostly. There is also a setting where you can force parameterization for all your queries. Search MSDN for this topic, should help you in deciding what's best.

However, this said, Stored Procedures remains a good way to to interact with the DB from your applications as it provides an additional security layer.

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 3):

This article explains it pretty well:
https://codingsight.com/dynamic-sql-vs-stored-procedure/

From my experience, Stored Procedures are definitely faster, because of decreased network traffic (don't have to send the whole query) and caching of the procedure and query plans.

I ran code similar to the following on a table filled with user logon data.

"select top 1 * from Logons where ComputerName=@ComputerName order by LogonTime desc"

It took 2 hours to run the query on 7000 computer names.

When I placed the query into a stored procedure, it took about a minute to run on 7000 computer names.

I'm certain that taking 1 second vs a 10 milliseconds per query doesn't make a big difference to humans if you are running the query just once.  However, if you need to run the query one thousand times, it's a difference of 1000 seconds (approx. 16 min) vs 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Another issues that is over looked, compare the network traffic between the web server and the database server of this-

exec someproc @var1='blah', @var2='blah', @var3='blah'

To this-

Select field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6....field30
join table1 on table2.field12 = table1.field12
where blah blah blah
and table1.field3 = @var1 and table2.field44 = @var2 and (table1.field1 is null or table1.field1 = @var3.......

See the difference? For 99% of us this probably won't matter, but for some of you writing high performance apps this might, though there are probably some caching or other ways of dealing with this.

I think a lot of people who claim there is no difference between adhoc queries and stored procedures are generally using tables as object stores for whatever ORM they are using, and that is fine.  There are still a lot of heavy data driven enterprise apps, rightly or wrongly, that have 1000+ line stored procedures. You may end up working on them.  Also, for those of you who may have to make changes in production every once in a while and need to bypass the formal process it is *a lot* easier to do that in the database than in production compiled code. Alter proc...done. Cowboy, horrible, evil, happens.  Yes I know doing this is an unforgivable sin in many of your minds, sign of shear slop...but it happens. Just something to think about too.

I know the latest tools generally make using stored procs a pain in the rear if you expect all your entities to be generated nicely for you, but stored procs still have their place sometimes.

Comment: Say you have a grid that shows 20 records at a time, but your query returns 20,000 matching records.  With entity framework you can do paging in your code, so that cuts down the data from 20,000 records to 20  records being sent down to the browser.  But 20,000 records are still sent from the database server to the web server.  With stored procs you can handle the paging logic in the proc itself, so 20 records get sent from the database server to the web server and then to the client.  Less traffic between your database server and your web server. Something else to think about.

Comment: [redundant], deleted.

Comment: This is less true now with Entity Framework, it seems to handle just getting the 20 records that it needs without the database server sucking the 20,000 records as in our example.  Data traffic is still an issue though between webserver and database server.  Stored procs cut down on that.

Answer (score 1):

stored procedures are compiled and cached. But SQL statements will be compared to existing execution plans and if a match is present used, thus nullifying somewhat any advantage.

Whats the actual performance difference after a number of executions ?

Comment: ? What does it means this? The results is cached or just the SQL query?

Comment: @marc_s I was still writing the answer. I guess I should know the rules. Law of the jungle and all that. And a sql query will only be be equally performant to a sproc after its first run,when the execution plan is present, unlike a sproc which is on creation.

Comment: TBH, I didnt talk about Parametrized SQL queries. I talk about execute a query from client like `sql = “Select * from Employees where Lastname = ‘” & ddl.selecteditem.text & “‘”`, not `sql = “Select * from Employees where Lastname =@LastName”`

Comment: @marc_s Er, in this case, I am not sure. Thats why I asked the questioner to test for the actual performance difference.

Comment: @marc_s : I know. But we are not talking about SQL Injection (which I can avoid adding a great escape of charaters). So SP are faster than these such simple query for the "execution plan"? Can you be more specific? Can't understand what do you mean :)

Comment: @markzzz: don't even try to start escaping your string values - **just use parametrized queries!** It's the easiest and safest way to go!

Comment: @markzzz: as for the speed advantage of stored procs - see my answer. The point is: if you send queries that are different all the time, then each query must be analyzed, "compiled", then executed - plus you're wasting ("polluting") the plan cache with execution plans that will never be reused - again hurting your overall system performance

Comment: Thanks you marc_s, you answer is perfect! Anyway, I really can't find an example which an escaped SQL string could be dangerous for an SQL Injection... really :)

Comment: @markzzz: look at [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139199/can-i-protect-against-sql-injection-by-escaping-single-quote-and-surrounding-use) and its answers - has tons of good links and samples why a simple "escape the single quotes" won't do. Also [see MSDN docs on SQL injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, and sorry! I use to Escaping to prevent SQL Injection on PHP/MySql in the past, never on SQL Server :)

Comment: in fact this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php will avoid any SQL Injection. Not sure, but this is OT! Maybe i'll open a specific topic :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unlike standard SQL statements, stored procedures are compiled and optimized by the database server. This optimization involves using information about the structure of a particular database that's required at execution time by the stored procedure. This process of storing execution information (the execution plan) is a tremendous time saver, especially if the stored procedure is called many times.

Speed is also improved by the fact that stored procedures run entirely on the database server - there's no need to pass large chunks of SQL code over a network. For a simple SELECT statement, that might not make a big difference, but in cases where we perform a series of loops and calculations, it can have a significant effect.

Comment: This is not entirely true; a properly parametrized query is just as much compiled and stored in the plan cache on your SQL Server - there's really not much (if any) difference in terms of execution speed/performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stored procedures sometimes run a little bit faster because or using RPC calls when possible
2. SP runs faster for queries that have to be recompiled - for ex. - using temp tables creations somewhere in the middle