# How to apply CASE in left join table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, case

I have one query for MySQL, and need to left join twice. There are four tables A, B, C, D, and two possibilities, if A.label is null then,

```
select ... from A
left join B on B.name=A.name
left join D on B.bid=D.id;
```

otherwise, if A.label is not null, I have

```
select ... from A
left join C on C.name=A.name
left join D on C.cid=D.id;
```

If I want to merge these two queries into one via CASE condition, what should I do?

Comment: Can't you just combine the two queries with UNION?

Comment: or better yet... create a stored procedure and pass A.label as a parameter to determine which query to use?

Comment: I have not tried that yet, is the stored procedure faster for big data query?

Comment: It's always up for debate, but [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559443/why-execute-stored-procedures-is-faster-than-sql-query-from-a-script) to see one way look at it.

My suggestion for the stored procedure was purely from the angle of keeping your query from getting unnecessarily massive and keeping the readability simple.  It would essentially let you say, "if @parameter = A, then run this query, else run that query."

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I follow what you're after, but you can add to your `JOIN` criteria and then use `COALESCE()`:

```
select COALESCE(b.name,c.name) Name
    ....
from A
left join B 
   on B.name=A.name
   AND A.label IS NULL
left join D 
   on B.bid=D.id
left join C 
   on C.name=A.name
   AND A.label IS NOT NULL
left join E
   on C.cid=E.id
```

Comment: This makes the assumption that when `A.label IS NULL` then `b.name` is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your queries don't product duplicate rows, you can do both joins in one query.  Then determine which value to use by incorporating a `case` statement in the `select` clause:

```
select A.*,
       (case when a.label is null then b.value else c.value end) as value,
       . . . 
from A left join
     B
     on B.name = A.name left join
     C
     on C.name = A.name left join
     D
     on C.cid = D.id;
```

Comment: It is possible to have duplicate rows. And also all of tables are huge, in this case all of the tables are loaded into memory and it will be a problem

Comment: @lanyou . . . If you are using `union all`, you are getting the same duplicate rows that this would produce.  With indexes on `C(name)` and `B(name)`, I wouldn't be surprised if this were the best performing.

Comment: But A can be only NULL or not NULL, so I think there won't be duplicate results

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION:

```
select ... from A
left join B on B.name=A.name
left join D on B.bid=D.id;
where A.label IS NULL
UNION ALL
select ... from A
left join C on C.name=A.name
left join D on C.cid=D.id
WHERE A.label IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: It's also my current solution, just want to find some other better way. And I use Union All instead of Union, cuz it will be faster for big data table query

Comment: If you do it in one query I think it will be inefficient, because it will join with tables that aren't needed for that row.