# MsSQL Server SP vs Query?

Tags: sql-server

SP or Query, which works better?

Comment: Your question is very broad. Please add a minimum viable example.

Comment: I am writing queries from very large DBs. The inquiries are coming back in a very long time. If I convert the queries I write to SP, will there be performance difference? Does the SP work faster?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559443/why-execute-stored-procedures-is-faster-than-sql-query-from-a-script

Comment: Do some research! This quesiton is answered multiple times... In short: A `VIEW` (=Query) is meant to **read** data, while a `STORED PROCEDURE` is meant **to do** something. Fastest in most cases is single statement *ad-hoc* SQL. But there is no general answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedure is group your query; rather also not to only write a adhoc query but write your business logic which will eventually end up executing multiple queries.

Again if it's SP then you end up transmitting very less data over the network when calling from your application code rather than writing up a huge adhoc query.

Again you can have granular privilege by wrapping your query in SP. Along with it .. you can use `Transaction` / error handling `TRY .. CATCH` etc..

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

The SP provides less data transfer, easier error checking, and more performance. Did I get right?

Comment: @DemirciMustafa, yes ... almost.