# Avoid MySQL Injection replacing single and double quotes

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection

to sanitize user input we usually use mysql_real_escape_string, but for example if i want to escape: O'Brian it will return O\'Brian and I don't really like this because if i want to print this name, I have to strip slasheseverytime. 
So I thought to use this function:

```
$search = array("'", '"');
$replace = array("´", "“");
$str_clean = str_replace($search, $replace, "O'Brian");
```

Is this simple function protecting me from MySQL-Injection?
Thank very much and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Chk this It will help you Up:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139199/can-i-protect-against-sql-injection-by-escaping-single-quote-and-surrounding-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, obviously it's protecting from `SQL Injection` attacks

It Escapes special characters in the `unescaped_string`, taking into account the current character set of the connection so that it is safe to place it in a `mysql_query()`.

Comment: I always use UTF-8, so I am protected also from hex strings like 0x27, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

No - no more escaping!

Use `mysqli` or `PDO` and prepared statements

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to use an object oriented style :(

Comment: mysqli has non-OOP options as well

Answer (score 2):

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) does add the `\` for string escaping only and does not add them to the database, so you don't have to use stripslashes while displaying the content.

If you are really getting the `\` stored in the database, do `off` the [`magic_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)

Comment: magic_quote is off ;) So I have to use mysql_real_escape_string only for SELECT query and not also for UPDATE or INSERT, right?

Comment: @SimoneVerzino: You need it where you needs to escape strings for mysql.

Answer (score 2):

You should always use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape input. This is for when you're *writing* values into your database, not when you're *reading* values from your database. When you write "O\'Brian" to your database, it's stored as "O'Brian", and when you read it back out, you should also get "O'Brian" (and won't need to strip the slashes, since they don't exist).

Comment: OK, but if I have to do a SELECT FROM USERS WHERE name = 'O'Brian' I must escape it, and with my function I will solve the problem?

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to escape the variable there as well. So something like `$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user); mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE name = '$user'");`