# Is String.split() function safe?

Tags: java, sql, security, jdbc

One day I was talking with a friend about one of his server applications for a little flash game.
The server communicates with a mysql database. And I found this request:

```
"UPDATE phpbb_users SET patojdur = '" + this.score + "' WHERE user_id = '" + this.user_id + "'"
```

As this.score is data entered by the user, I asked him if it wasn't unsafe to put that directly in the SQL request, and take the risk of an SQL injection.

But he answered me: "No, because this.score is an `user_request.split("'")[1]`, the split is protecting me and you can't put a `'` to inject."

My question isn't if he made the right choice by doing that, because I know he won't change his mind, but What he said made me curious about a thing: is split really safe? Does it really prevent the splitted character to pass whatever you do? Or even if it's risky, put a `var.split("'")` finally prevent you from `'` injection?

Edit: I've read the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537368/how-can-sanitation-that-escapes-single-quotes-be-defeated-by-sql-injection-in-sq) but mine is specific to the Split method, and doesn't apply only on SQL database, in other word my question is:

Does `var.split('c')` really prevent c to be in the final string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still dangerous. Of course it depends on the SQL variant. Backslash is by the standard an escape. Easy would be `\x27` (if that works) for apostrophe; but already havoc is possible if the injected string ends with a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

'ʼ;DROP TABLE myTable--'

there are cases where Unicode conversion might slip through a single quote, since you are only explicitly replacing one representation of the sincle quote charater with an empty string (thats what split does ..)

see: https://siderite.dev/blog/why-doubling-single-quotes-is-not.html

Comment: Thank you, hopefully jdbc don't allow multiple querys on one statement. But as everyone said, what my friend is doing is still dangerous!