# Double Quote Injection

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, code-injection

Is it enough to replace all single quotes in a T-SQL statement with double quotes to prevent injections?

I have this PHP function to escape user input which is then executed directly.

```php
<?php

    function clean($input) {
        return str_replace('\'', '\'\'', $input);
    }

    echo 'INSERT INTO Temp ([test]) VALUES (\'' .clean($_GET['test']). '\')';
```

Example: `$_GET['test']` is `'test`, it would be escaped to `'''test'`.

I know, I should use prepared statements, but I want to know if this is vulnerable.

Comment: Using a prepared (parametrised) statement is always the way to go.

Comment: In short, Yes, you can use preg_replace to modify your output.

Comment: No, it's not. sanitizing inputs is the wrong way to go. I remember about 13-14 years ago getting our databases hacked via injection even though we did have a string replace sanitation function and everything that went to the database was through it. Use parameters. That's what they are there for.

Comment: Take a look at [this question and the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537368/how-can-sanitation-that-escapes-single-quotes-be-defeated-by-sql-injection-in-sq). It's not exactly like your example, but it may help you to understand why using parameterized queries is the best approach.