# SQL-safe method

Tags: php, sql-injection

**Context:** I'm trying to convince a friend to switch to using parameterized queries to prevent SQL injections and other malicious attempts as that is the standards these days but he has a mentality of "*If it's not broken, don't fix it.*"

Here's the code he currently uses:

```
function sql_safe($text) {
    return str_replace("'", "''", $text);
}
```

Is there a way for me to break this function to illustrate to him that this approach is not advisable any more?

#### Additional Info

It's being used as a general means to protect the system from SQL injections so that user inputs are escaped properly. But I feel like his approach could break at certain scenarios which I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: Can you add a bit more context how this is intended to be used please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's being used as a general means to protect the system from SQL injections so that user inputs are escaped properly. But I feel like his approach could break at certain scenarios which I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: [Add such additional information to your question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/152809/edit) please, rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
<?php
function sql_safe($text) {
    return str_replace("'", "''", $text);
}
echo "SELECT * FROM db WHERE field = '" . sql_safe($argv[1]) . "';\n";
```

And here's the most obvious way of breaking it:

```
$ php ./x.php "\' OR TRUE; -- MySQL"
SELECT * FROM db WHERE field = '\'' OR TRUE; -- MySQL';
```

Stack Overflow has covered the topic of SQL injection extensively over the years. See for example [Can I protect against SQL Injection by escaping single-quote and surrounding user input with single-quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139199/can-i-protect-against-sql-injection-by-escaping-single-quote-and-surrounding-use) . There's a neat trick in there that exploits "maximum length of string" to truncate just one of the replacement `''`s.

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful. Time for some convincing.